# Probability of P(A|B) given P(A), P(B)

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Given $P(A)=0.9$ and $P(B)=0.8$.

How to prove that $P(A|B)\ge 0.875$ ?

Comment: Do you know of any formulae to compute $P(A|B)$?

Comment: The definition of conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$ is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{ P(B)}$$
$$=\frac{P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)}{ P(B)}$$
$$=\frac{0.9+0.8-P(A\cup B)}{ 0.8}$$
$$\ge \frac{0.9+0.8-1}{ 0.8}$$
$$\ge 0.875$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, and $\Pr(A\cup B)\le 1$, we have $\Pr(A\cap B)\ge 0.7$.

Now use the fact that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)$.  We get $\Pr(A\mid B)\ge \frac{0.7}{0.8}$.